# Override Save to create multiple objects for range()

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to override Django form save method to be able to create multiple objects at once.

I have an AvailableHours model :

```
class AvailableHours(models.Model):
    free_date = models.ForeignKey(AvailableDates,null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='freedate')
    free_hours_from = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    free_hours_to = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True,)
    status = models.BooleanField(null=True,default=True,)
```

and I have a ModelForm for this class :

```
class TimeGenerator(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AvailableHours

        fields = ['free_date','free_hours_from','free_hours_to','status']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        m = super(TimeGenerator, self).save(commit=False)
        self.free_hours_from = self.cleaned_data['free_hours_from']
        self.free_hours_to = self.cleaned_data['free_hours_from'] +1
        m.save()
        for hour in range(self.cleaned_data['free_hours_from'],self.cleaned_data['free_hours_to']+1):
            self.free_hours_from = self.cleaned_data['free_hours_from']+hour
            self.free_hours_to = self.cleaned_data['free_hours_from']+hour+1
            print(hour)
            m.save()
```

I want to create multiple AvailableHours object like this:
if the form is set free_hours_from = 13 and free_hours_to=16
so the save method creates 13-14 , 14-15, 15-16

I wrote a code above in forms and overrided save() but its not working.
anyone has a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create items and save these in bulk with:

```
class TimeGenerator(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AvailableHours

        fields = ['free_date', 'free_hours_from', 'free_hours_to', 'status']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        base_item = super().save(commit=False)
        frm = self.cleaned_data['free_hours_from']
        to = self.cleaned_data['free_hours_to']
        items = [
            AvailableHours(
                free_date=base_item.free_date,
                status=base_item.status,
                free_hours_from=hour,
                free_hours_to=hour + 1,
            )
            for hour in range(frm, to)
        ]
        if commit:
            AvailableHours.objects.bulk_create(items)
        return items
```

That being said, it is odd that the `AvailableHours` has a `free_hours_to` field if that is always the `free_hours_from` plus one.

Comment: nicely done. btw edit : to = self.cleaned_data['free_hours_to'] . not to = self.cleaned_data['free_hours_from']

Comment: @Essiprog: aaarrrggghhh... thanks.